# Accessing a private class from another file

Tags: c#, .net, private

I would like to keep my .cs files separate, mainly because I think it looks neater that way. In one .cs file I have the Form.cs. I'm working in the .NET framework 2.0. So I have a different myClass.cs file with several methods. As I want users of the form to give authentication before accessing the web services called in the method, I want the information to be private.
I've seen in examples and tutorials that this is no problem normally within the same file. However, in my goal I want the info to be in the class.cs file.. For example I want the class in myClass.cs file to look like this (this is rough yet):

```
    private class SessionData
    {
        private String fTicket;
        private string otherData;

        public SessionData( String ticket, String otherData)
        {
            fTicket = ticket;
            fotherData = otherData;
        }

        public String getTicket{ return fTicket; };
    }
```

And then access it in the form.cs file...

```
    private void LogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         myClass sessInfo = new myClass();

         string myTicket = sessInfo.SessionData();
         }
    }
```

The problem is that because it's private I can't access it in Form.cs. Is it even possible to do this? I've seen a bunch of examples and tips but always within the same file. 
This is the basic idea anyways that's in my head. If there is another way I'm open for advice!

Do I have to make a public constructor and can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define the nested class in a seperate file for example 'SessionData.cs' by just wrapping it inside the partial class which should have access to it.

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private class SessionData
    {
        public void getTicket();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually yes that would be what I was aiming for. Basically I just wanted data to be separated into another file.cs. I just don't think the data should be in a Form.cs.. only buttons and such things.. But if it's just my wanting something esthetic then of course I'll opt for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is confusion about the need for credentials to remain "private" in the sense of not broadcasting the information, and the terminology used for OO accessibility "private" in the sense of type scope. The two are not interchangeable and are completely separate ideas.

Your solution of trying to secure sensitive information using C# type accessibility is nonsensical and is definitely the wrong way to go. I would perhaps ask another question about how best to protect sensitive information during user log-in.

---

<sub>**Old Answer:**</sub>

I assume that `SessionData` is a nested class? You cannot have private classes defined in namespaces.

If you define a private nested class, only the type that contains this private class will be able to use it, regardless of constructor accessibility.

So really, if you want to expose `SessionData`, make it public.

If the code is all in the same assembly, you could also make `SessionData` internal:

```
internal class SessionData { }
```

Code outside of this assembly will not be able to reference `SessionData`.

Comment: Actually yes, it is nested. Well I wanted the ticket to be properly secure. And the way I had it split into 2 files, it only worked with public. I was wondering if it was possible to have it secure and in two separate files, or how do people do this sort of thing with logon forms? Everything in the same Form.cs file?

Comment: @SuusvdVen The idea of security of sensitive information has nothing to do with C# type accessibility, so your solution to making the information "private" is the wrong way to go.